# 1-sample vs 2-sample t-test for difference of means

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a sample mean associated with the current fiscal quarter and want to compare it to the previous quarter (also a sample mean) to determine if the estimated population parameter increased or decreased. Is this best done via a 1-sample or 2-sample difference of means t-test? The obvious answer would be 2-sample but could I also assume the previous quarter’s mean is the population mean (as my null hypothesis) and thus use the 1-sample test with the 1 sample being the current quarter’s mean?

Comment: With enough data, it won't matter.  1-sample is usually done when the observational unit is a single person or patient.  But like I said, the reduction in power would be very small when the data are large enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two samples, you should not be doing a one sample test.

A one sample test where you take the first sample as if they were population figures leads the test to have a higher actual type I error rate than you chose.

However, with time series you also have the additional issue that the usual assumption of independence is unlikely to hold (and indeed, if you don't have stationarity you have additional issues).

Comment: Can you elaborate on your comments about the time series? Why does the assumption of independence not hold?

Comment: Most typically with data observed over time, points nearer together in time tend to be more alike than points farther apart in time; this suggests positive autocorrelation (it can have other causes, but they would all be a problem). Time series that are i.i.d would be pretty rare.

Comment: Can you recommend any online resources to better understand the issue if i.i.d. and time series? How do I test for significance between two time series? What exactly determines if a sample is or is not a time series? Since all process are a function of time, wouldn’t all samples be considered time series?